# Multiple Calls to Custom Hook not yielding expected result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having a hard time understanding why the onClick event handler (which invokes 2 calls to a custom hook wrapper function) is not responding properly. I expect that everytime I click the button in the example would swap its border color from green to red based on a value that is being incremented. I understand the example is rudimentary and could easily be solved by conditioning the error prop on the value.value instead of sharing , but this is a simplified example of a more complex interaction, and I have boiled down the issue to a simple example for clarification. Any help would be appreciated.
https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-hooks-with-closure-issue-2fc6g?file=/index.js

index.js

```
import useValueErrorPair from "./useValueErrorPair";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  ${props =>
    props.error ? "border: 3px solid #ff0000;" : "border: 3px solid #00ff00;"}
`;

const e = React.createElement;

const DemoComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue, setError] = useValueErrorPair(0, false);
  console.log(value);
  return (
    <Button
      error={value.error}
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setError((value.value + 1) % 2 === 1); // If number of clicks is odd => error.
        setValue(value.value + 1); // Increment the state hook for value.
      }}
    >
      Click Me For Problems!
    </Button>
  );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render(e(DemoComponent), domContainer);

export default DemoComponent;
```

useValueErrorPair.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useValueErrorPair = (initialValue, initialError) => {
  const [v, setV] = useState({ value: initialValue, error: initialError });
  const setValue = newValue => {
    setV({ error: v.error, value: newValue });
  };

  const setError = newError => {
    if (newError !== v.error) setV({ error: newError, value: v.value });
  };

  return [v, setValue, setError];
};

export default useValueErrorPair;
```

Snippet:

```js
const { useState } = React;
    
const useValueErrorPair = (initialValue, initialError) => {
  const [v, setV] = useState({ value: initialValue, error: initialError });
  const setValue = newValue => {
    setV({ error: v.error, value: newValue });
  };

  const setError = newError => {
    if (newError !== v.error) setV({ error: newError, value: v.value });
  };

  return [v, setValue, setError];
};

const DemoComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue, setError] = useValueErrorPair(0, false);
  console.log(value);
  return (
    <button type="button" className={value.error ? "error" : "okay"}
      onClick={e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setError((value.value + 1) % 2 === 1); // If number of clicks is odd => error.
        setValue(value.value + 1); // Increment the state hook for value.
      }}
    >
      Click Me For Problems!
    </button>
  );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#root");
const e = React.createElement;
ReactDOM.render(e(DemoComponent), domContainer);
```

```css
.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.okay {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the post format. I couldn't figure out how to make snippets work with 2 javascript files. It seems to support one html, one css, and one js file so I just put the code in raw.

Comment: Don't use two "files," create a single combined snippet with all irrelevancies (such as `styled-components`) removed, so we can focus on the actual problem (the hook).

Comment: I've done it for you using the code from the question.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was incorrect briefly (I missed out part of the necessary change to `setError`). It's fixed now.

Comment: And thanks for editing the code into the question!

Comment: Thank you for fixing that. I got sidetracked into a meeting and abandoned this for a few hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your setter functions are using stale state. When setting new state based on existing state, you should use the callback form so you're always dealing with up-to-date information. In your case, the call to `setError` was working fine, but then the call to `setValue` was using a stale copy of `v` and undoing the change that `setError` had made.

If we use the callback form, the problem disappears, see `***` comments:

```
const useValueErrorPair = (initialValue, initialError) => {
    const [v, setV] = useState({ value: initialValue, error: initialError });
    const setValue = newValue => {
        // *** Use the callback form when setting state based on existing state
        setV(({error}) => ({error, value: newValue}));
    };
  
    const setError = newError => {
        // *** Again
        setV(prev => {
            if (newError !== prev.error) {
                return { error: newError, value: prev.value };
            }
            // No change
            return prev;
        });
    };
  
    return [v, setValue, setError];
};
```

```js
const { useState } = React;
    
const useValueErrorPair = (initialValue, initialError) => {
    const [v, setV] = useState({ value: initialValue, error: initialError });
    const setValue = newValue => {
        // *** Use the callback form when setting state based on existing state
        setV(({error}) => ({error, value: newValue}));
    };
  
    const setError = newError => {
        // *** Again
        setV(prev => {
            if (newError !== prev.error) {
                return { error: newError, value: prev.value };
            }
            // No change
            return prev;
        });
    };
  
    return [v, setValue, setError];
};

const DemoComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue, setError] = useValueErrorPair(0, false);
    console.log(value);
    return (
        <button type="button" className={value.error ? "error" : "okay"}
            onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setError((value.value + 1) % 2 === 1); // If number of clicks is odd => error.
                setValue(value.value + 1); // Increment the state hook for value.
            }}
        >
          Click Me, It's Working!
        </button>
    );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#root");
const e = React.createElement;
ReactDOM.render(e(DemoComponent), domContainer);
```

```css
.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.okay {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

There's another advantage to doing that: You can make the setter functions *stable*, like the ones you get from `useState`, rather than recreating them every time (which can have knock-on effects causing components to re-render unnecessarily). For hooks, I prefer to use refs for stability rather than `useMemo` (or `useCallback`, which uses `useMemo`) since the `useMemo` docs say it's not a semantic guarantee. (It also reduces the number of functions you create and throw away.)

Here's what that would look like:

```
const useValueErrorPair = (initialValue, initialError) => {
    const [v, setV] = useState({ value: initialValue, error: initialError });
    const settersRef = useRef(null);
    if (!settersRef.current) {
        settersRef.current = {
            setValue: newValue => {
                setV(({error}) => ({error, value: newValue}));
            },
            setError: newError => {
                setV(prev => {
                    if (newError !== prev.error) {
                        // Update
                        return { error: newError, value: prev.value };
                    }
                    // No change
                    return prev;
                });
            },
        };
    }
  
    return [v, settersRef.current.setValue, settersRef.current.setError];
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React;
    
const useValueErrorPair = (initialValue, initialError) => {
    const [v, setV] = useState({ value: initialValue, error: initialError });
    const settersRef = useRef(null);
    if (!settersRef.current) {
        settersRef.current = {
            setValue: newValue => {
                setV(({error}) => ({error, value: newValue}));
            },
            setError: newError => {
                setV(prev => {
                    if (newError !== prev.error) {
                        // Update
                        return { error: newError, value: prev.value };
                    }
                    // No change
                    return prev;
                });
            },
        };
    }
  
    return [v, settersRef.current.setValue, settersRef.current.setError];
};

const DemoComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue, setError] = useValueErrorPair(0, false);
    console.log(value);
    return (
        <button type="button" className={value.error ? "error" : "okay"}
            onClick={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                setError((value.value + 1) % 2 === 1); // If number of clicks is odd => error.
                setValue(value.value + 1); // Increment the state hook for value.
            }}
        >
          Click Me, It's Working!
        </button>
    );
};

const domContainer = document.querySelector("#root");
const e = React.createElement;
ReactDOM.render(e(DemoComponent), domContainer);
```

```css
.error {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.okay {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great stuff. By stable you mean that there will only be one reference to the setValue and setError functions and not new instances of those functions created everytime a different component calls the useValueErrorPair custom hook? I guess this also works because you're using a functional form of the setState part of the useState hook (which I'll admit I hadn't seen before).

Comment: @CodeoftheWarrior - Yes, exactly, like the setter from [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate): *"Note: React guarantees that setState function identity is stable and won’t change on re-renders."* We need to use the callback form anyway (because of the stale state issue), and it also makes it possible to do that. Happy coding!